# How to show that how many field checked dynamically with j query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code with adding fields dynamically with checkbox and radio box changes dynamically. I want show how many checkbox/radio i checked will be shown in front of 'Required correct answer'.
For this first click on 'insert new' then check the checkbox/radio and how many you check need to shown in front of 'Required Correct ans'.
Please resize the window

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var i=0;
    var q = 4;  

    $('#insertnewqstnbtn').click(function(){  
        i++;
        $('#newqstndiv').append('<div id="appenddiv'+i+'" class="ms-create-new-form"><h2 class= "ms-font-xl"> Add New Question <span><a href="javascript:;" id="'+i+'" class="closebtn"><a/></span></h2><div class="multichoice-question-btn"><div class="item"><span>Multiple Choice?</span><input type = "checkbox" id = "toggleaddqstn_'+i+'"><div class= "toggle"><label for="toggleaddqstn_'+i+'"><i></i></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-input-field-div"><input id="questiontxt'+i+'" type="text" placeholder="Enter question text here" class="ms-title-field question" /></div><div class="ms-form-first-group form-for-ans"><div class="ms-ans-text"><p>Answer</p></div><div class="ms-correct-text"><p>Correct?</p></div></div><div class="border-bottom-line-ans"></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field'+i+'1"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option 1 text" id="option1'+i+'" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="checkboxn1'+i+'" name="checboxname'+i+'" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn1'+i+'"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field'+i+'2"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option 2 text" id="option2'+i+'" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="checkboxn2'+i+'" name="checboxname'+i+'" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn2'+i+'"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field'+i+'3"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option 3 text" id="option3'+i+'" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" id="checkboxn3'+i+'" name="checboxname'+i+'" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn3'+i+'"></label></div></div></div><div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field'+i+'4"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option 4 text" id="option4'+i+'" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" name="checboxname'+i+'" id="checkboxn4'+i+'" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn4'+i+'"></label></div></div></div><span class="add-filed"><a href="javascript:;" id="add-field_'+i+'"></a></span><div class="ms-pagin-div" id="rqdoptionsdiv"><div class="ms-pagin-text"><p>Required correct answer</p></div><div class="ms-pagin-num" id="correctOptNum"><span>2</span><span>3</span><span class="active">4</span></div></div><button id="addnewqstnCancelbtn" class="newcoursecancelbtn">Cancel</button><button id="addnewqstnbtn_'+i+'" class="ms-cm-button add-detail-btn createquestion" style="width:40%;">Create</button><label id="chkpointErrMsg"></label><div class="border-bottom-line mb-bottom-15"></div></div>');

        var checkMultiChoice = $("#toggleaddqstn_"+ i);
        var addMoreBtn = $("#add-field_" + i);

        addMoreBtn.click(function(){
            var parentDiv = "#appenddiv" + i;
            var lastDiv = ".ms-form-second-ground:last";

            var addFieldSplit = $(this).attr('id');
            var fieldSplit = addFieldSplit.split('_');
            var fieldSplitFirst = fieldSplit[0];
            var fieldSplitTwo = fieldSplit[1];
            q++;
            if (checkMultiChoice.prop("checked") == true) {
                $(parentDiv + ".ms-form-second-ground:last").after('<div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field'+i+''+q+'"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option '+q+' text" id="option'+q+''+i+'" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="checkbox" name="checboxname'+i+'" id="checkboxn'+q+''+i+'" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn'+q+''+i+'"></label></div></div></div>');
            } else if (checkMultiChoice.prop("checked") == false) {
                $('<div class="ms-form-second-ground question-with-ans" id="option-field'+i+''+q+'"><div class="ms-ans-text-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Option '+q+' text" id="option'+q+''+i+'" class="ms-title-field" /></div><div class="ms-check-icon chk"><div class="round"><input type="radio" name="checboxnamee'+i+'" id="checkboxn'+q+''+i+'" class="cm-box"/><label for="checkboxn'+q+''+i+'"></label></div></div></div>').insertAfter(parentDiv + " "+ ".ms-form-second-ground:last");
            }
        });
        var splitCheck = (checkMultiChoice.attr('id')).split("_");
        var splicheckfirst = splitCheck[0];
        var splichecksecond = splitCheck[1];

        checkMultiChoice.click(function(){
            if ((checkMultiChoice).prop("checked") == true) {
                for (var input = 1; input <= q; input++) {
                    var btnOption = "checkboxn"+input+splichecksecond;

                    $("#"+btnOption).attr('type','checkbox');
                }
             } else if ((checkMultiChoice).prop("checked") == false) {
                for(var input = 1; input <= q; input++){
                    var btnOption = "checkboxn"+input+splichecksecond;
                    $("#"+btnOption).attr('type','radio');
                }
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.closebtn', function(){  
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#appenddiv'+button_id+'').remove();
        });
    });  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rajanchopra21/0xe4rujL/1/

Comment: Please try and produce a [mcve] illustrating what you want.  I feel there is code that is not relevant in what you have provided here, and certainly in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

`$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')` return an array with all checked checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Franceso Russo said, there are many ways you can get the required result. To get just the count of checked checkbox or radio buttons, you can just find the length of the checked elements.

```
/**
 * For checkbox
 */
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length
// OR
$("input[type='checkbox']").filter("checked").length

/**
 * For radio buttons
 */
$("input[type="radio']:checked").length
// OR
$("input[type='radio']").filter("checked").length
```

However, above code will get you count of all checkbox or radio on that page.
If you want to get the specific ones, just add the respective identifier to the above expression. For example,

```
/**
 * For checkbox
 */
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='someCheckboxName']:checked").length
// OR
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='someCheckboxName']").filter("checked").length

/**
 * For Radio Buttons
 */
$("input[type="radio'][name='someRadioButtonName']:checked").length
// OR
$("input[type='radio'][name='someRadioButtonName']").filter("checked").length
```